# $\ker A \cap\mathrm{Im} A = {0} \Rightarrow \ker A + \mathrm{Im} A = R^n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose, we have a linear operator A on $R^n$ such that $n>1$. I'm trying to prove that if $\ker A \cap \mathrm{Im}(A) = {0}$, then $\ker A + \mathrm{Im}(A) = R^n$.

Generally, $$\dim (\ker A + \mathrm{Im}(A)) = \dim \ker A + \dim \mathrm{Im}(A) - \dim (\ker A \cap \mathrm{Im}(A))$$

Rank-nullity theorem simplifies the previous equality: $$\dim (\ker A + \mathrm{Im}(A)) = n - \dim (\ker A \cap \mathrm{Im}(A))$$

If $\ker A \cap \mathrm{Im}(A) = {0}$, then $\dim (\ker A \cap \mathrm{Im}(A)) = 0$. Thus, $\dim (\ker A + \mathrm{Im}(A)) = n = \dim R^n$

I'm not sure whether I am allowed to deduce that $\ker A + \mathrm{Im}(A) = R^n$? If not, then how to (dis)prove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, you are allowed since

$$\left(U\le V\;\wedge\;\dim V<\infty\right)\implies\left(U=V\iff \dim U=\dim V\right)$$

For a very quick proof of the above just choose *any* basis of $\,U\,$ and complete it to a basis of $\,V\,$ ...